# I get error No such module 'Realm' in old project but no error in new projects - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For some reason I keep getting the **No such module 'Realm** error in an existing project where I'm trying to incorporate `Realm`, the funny thing is that I don't get the error in new projects.

The only difference I can see between the projects is that in the existing project where I'm getting the error I have a WatchOS app and not on the new projects.

This is how I'm installing `Realm` that works in any new project but not on the existing one.

1. Downloaded 'Realm' to my Desktop
2. Dragged and doped the appropriate version of `RealmSwift.framework` and `Realm.framework` to my project folder
3. Went to the `Embedded Binaries` clicked the + sign, selected `RealmSwift.framework` and `Realm.framework` and with the *Copy items if needed* option checked, I clicked the `Finish` button

Any idea what could be wrong?

Is the fact that I have a WatchOS app in the existing project the cause of the error?

I found [this thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4183) but in my case I'm NOT trying to use `Realm` in my WatchOS app, I'm only trying to import it in the iOS version.

### EDIT:

#### After trying different things I discovered that I only get the error on classes that are shared between iOS and WatchOS app but NO error on classes that are NOT shared.

#### Now the question is... *How to solve error No such module 'Realm' on classes that are shared between iOS and WatchOS?*

Comment: Have you given framework search path for your framework in Build Settings.Go to Build Settings->Search Paths->Framework Search Path and give the path where you have placed your framework .(the directory path) and try once.

Comment: @TusharSharma No, I have not. Excuse my ignorance but what is that link needed for, does that means that I need to point it to my Desktop to where I downloaded Realm? I thought that by having the `Copy items if needed` option checked was enough.Thanks.

Comment: Well usually when i add frameworks and get the similar issue as yours i add framework path. Sorry on that i never select copy item if needed.

Comment: I see. The funny thing is that new projects work without me having to add the `Framework Search Path`.  Thanks

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have tried different things but no luck. But I think I found a clue, I only get the `No such module Realm` error in classes that are shared between `iOS` and `WatchOS`. I tested it by entering a new class imported `import RealmSwift` and no error,  then I went and shared the class and then I got the error. I'm not sure what the workaround would be for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Carthage to generate your frameworks, I have a solution that might work for you without much effort. Carthage generates watchOS versions of the frameworks in its own folder under Build. You could copy those two framework]s [Realm, RealmSwift] into your project.